# Xpath not working using XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath

Based on this thread in which I am fixing the response from the sharepoint.

[Previous Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701352/removing-xml-declaration-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8-using-xslt-1-0/33701755#33701755)

**Response**

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <SharepointResponse xmlns="http://test.com.services.generic">
            <Sharepoint_Response>
                <CopyIntoItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
                    <CopyIntoItemsResult>0</CopyIntoItemsResult>
                    <Results>
                        <CopyResult ErrorCode="Success" DestinationUrl="http://archivelink.dev.test.com/enterprise"/>
                    </Results>
                </CopyIntoItemsResponse>
            </Sharepoint_Response>
        </SharepointResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I am converting this into JSONX and I need the value of `<CopyIntoItemsResult>0</CopyIntoItemsResult>`

```
< ErrorCode="Success"
```

and

```
DestinationUrl="http://archivelink.dev.test.com/enterprise"/>
```

Below are the Xpath I used 
1) **CopyIntoItemsResult** `<xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='SharepointResponse']/*[local-name()='Sharepoint_Response']/*[local-name()='CopyIntoItemsResponse']/*[local-name()='CopyIntoItemsResult']/text()"/>`

2) **ErrorCode**  `/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='SharepointResponse']/*[local-name()='Sharepoint_Response']/*[local-name()='CopyIntoItemsResponse']/*[local-name()='Results']/*[local-name()='CopyResult']/@*[local-name()='ErrorCode']`

3) **DestinationUrl** `/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='SharepointResponse']/*[local-name()='Sharepoint_Response']/*[local-name()='CopyIntoItemsResponse']/*[local-name()='Results']/*[local-name()='CopyResult']/@*[local-name()='DestinationUrl']`

The problem is I am not getting any values for and I am not able to figure it out where I am doing it wrong?

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really show your XSLT but it depends on your template match. If you used the asterisk (`*`), your XPaths should work. Alternatively, you can use the backslash (`/`) in template match but remove that at beginning of each XPath.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

 <xsl:template match="*">
    <data>    
        <CopyIntoItemsResult>
            <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*
                    [local-name()='SharepointResponse']/*[local-name()='Sharepoint_Response']/*
                    [local-name()='CopyIntoItemsResponse']/*
                    [local-name()='CopyIntoItemsResult']/text()"/>
        </CopyIntoItemsResult>
        <ErrorCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*
                    [local-name()='SharepointResponse']/*[local-name()='Sharepoint_Response']/*
                    [local-name()='CopyIntoItemsResponse']/*[local-name()='Results']/*
                    [local-name()='CopyResult']/@*[local-name()='ErrorCode']"/>
        </ErrorCode>
        <DestinationUrl>    
            <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*
                    [local-name()='SharepointResponse']/*[local-name()='Sharepoint_Response']/*
                    [local-name()='CopyIntoItemsResponse']/*[local-name()='Results']/*
                    [local-name()='CopyResult']/@*[local-name()='DestinationUrl']"/>
        </DestinationUrl>
    </data>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<data>
    <CopyIntoItemsResult>0</CopyIntoItemsResult>
    <ErrorCode>Success</ErrorCode>
    <DestinationUrl>http://archivelink.dev.test.com/enterprise</DestinationUrl>
</data>
```